# Joining two tables without filtering the data on the basis of joining condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables Table1 and Table2

**Table 1:**

```
ID1 |   C1  |   C2  |   C3
1   |   a   |   b   |   c
2   |   d   |   e   |   f
3   |   g   |   h   |   i
```

**Table 2:**

```
ID2 |   C4  |   C5  |   C6
2   |   k   |   l   |   m
```

I want to join Table 1 and Table 2 to get following results:

```
ID1 |   C1  |   C2  |   C3  |   C4  |   C5  |   C6
1   |   a   |   b   |   c   |   -   |   -   |   -
2   |   d   |   e   |   f   |   k   |   l   |   m
3   |   g   |   h   |   i   |   -   |   -   |   -
```

The two tables are being joined on condition `ID1=ID2` and and when this condition is not true the rest of the columns from table 2 should automatically be `null`. The total number of columns in result should always be equal to number of columns in Table1. The IDs in Table 1 are super set of IDs in Table 2. What kind of join and joining condition should I use?

Comment: You should use a `LEFT JOIN ON ID1=ID2`.

Comment: Would be a good idea for you to spend a little time here. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: What you are looking for is known as a `OUTER JOIN`, a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to be specific if you want everything from the first table, and blanks from the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A left outer join assuming the first table is used first. A SQL syntax for the above would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1  
LEFT JOIN Table2 On Table1.ID1=Table2.ID2
```